# System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed file.'

Tags: c#, wpf, itext

For the past week or so this exception is causing me a headache, I can't for the life of me fix it. I'm using iTextSharp to merge PDF files and add a watermark on them if the user chooses to do so.

**Here's the code for merging :**

```
private void CreateMergedPdf(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(pdfname, FileMode.Create)) {

            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(pdfDoc, stream);

            pdfDoc.Open();
            int i = 0;


            foreach (File_class newpdf in AddedPDFs)
            {
                (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i++);

                if (newpdf.toMerge)
                {
                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(newpdf.file_path);
                    pdf.AddDocument(reader); //<!> Exception here

                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => progBtxt.Text = "Merging file #" + newpdf.file_id + "..."); //Dispatcher.Invoke since UI is on seperate thread

                    if (add_wtrmk)//This is called for every FILE
                    {
                        AddWatermark(reader, stream);
                    }
                }


            }
     }
 }
```

**And here's the code for the watermark:**

```
 private void AddWatermark(PdfReader reader, FileStream stream)
    {
        using (PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))//This is called for every PAGE of the file
        {

            for (int pgIndex = 1; pgIndex <= reader.NumberOfPages; pgIndex++)
            {
                Rectangle pageRectangle = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pgIndex);
                PdfContentByte pdfData; //Contains graphics and text content of page returned by pdfstamper


                if (this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => dropdown.Text == "Under Content"))
                {
                    pdfData = pdfStamper.GetUnderContent(pgIndex);
                }
                else if (this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => dropdown.Text == "Over Content"))
                {
                    pdfData = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(pgIndex);
                }
                else//Just in case

                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong when adding the watermark");
                    return;
                }

                //Set font
                pdfData.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 40);

                //Create new graphics state and assign opacity
                PdfGState graphicsState = new PdfGState();
                graphicsState.FillOpacity = 0.25F;

                //Set graphics state to pdfcontentbyte
                pdfData.SetGState(graphicsState);

                //Color of watermark
                pdfData.SetColorFill(BaseColor.GRAY);

                pdfData.BeginText();

                //Show text as per position and rotation
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => pdfData.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, WtrmkTextbox.Text, pageRectangle.Width / 2, pageRectangle.Height / 2, 45));

                pdfData.EndText();

            }
        }
    }
```

The error appears on the code for merging, specifically the line "                   pdf.AddDocument(reader);" ***BUT*** I get this error only if I try to add watermarks on more than one files (with just one file it works perfectly).

I'm thinking either *I* am closing something too early, or addWatermark() does - I've tried changing our the *using* statemets to no avail. I must be missing something

Comment: My guess is that `PdfStamper` is closing the stream when you dispose of it in `AddWatermark`. It doesn't fail when you add the first page right? Just the second time after you've added a watermark?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: Ok, I suggest removing the `PdfStamper` using statement just to test the theory. If that fixes the problem then it is simply a matter of restructuring the code so that the inner dispose isn't called before the whole stream is finished.

Comment: The exception doesn't pop up, however the created PDF is corrupted/damaged. I'll look into restructuring the code

Comment: Okay, i passed the necessary arguements to AddWatermark() and added a simple if statement. Now everything works perfectly -- thanks for spending some of your time on my problem!

Comment: I don't know anything about the iTextSharp library, but given that the PdfStamper interface includes page indexes, it seems to me the developers intended it to be called once for an entire document instead of individually for every page. That approach would also clean up the structure I think.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help, I know how frustrating it can be to hit your head against the wall over and over again on a simple problem.

Comment: That was my original approach as well, it's way easier on the eyes, I changed to this in hopes of fixing things. I'll look on changing it

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it seems PdfStamper was the culprit, i passed the necessary arguements to AddWatermark() and added a simple if statement. Now everything works perfectly.

BIG thanks to [Mark Rucker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066291/mark-rucker)